# How to read multiple rows of Form elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have form elements in multiple rows. What is the best way to name these elements so that i can read all the values in the form and generate a JSON with the values? Since HTML does not support Arrays what is the best alternative?

Each row has 2 text elements and 1 Select element. These rows are generated dynamically.

Edit: Basically i want an easy way to convert my data into JSON so that i can pass it to a service.

Each of my row looks like this

```
<tr><td><input type="text"></input></td>
<td><select><option>Exact</option><option>Regex</option><option>Action</option></select></td>
<td><input type="text"></input></td></tr>

<tr><td><input type="text"></input></td>
<td><select><option>Exact</option><option>Regex</option><option>Action</option></select></td>
<td><input type="text"></input></td></tr> .....
```

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML does not support Arrays" ?

Comment: So if i have multiple rows of form elements, can i name the elements as textbox[0] textbox[1] etc?

Comment: Sure, you can also name them `textbox[]` or `textbox[name]`

Comment: And run a loop in Jquery to generate a JSON, any way to auto generate?

Comment: You no names to your input elements, is that a mistake in the edit or is that how your HTML actually looks?

Comment: I can add names, that is one of my questions, what is the best way to name them?

Comment: In array syntax. I have added an example in my answer of naming via array syntax.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* I understand. You can just change your HTML:

```
<div class="form"> // I prefer getting a namespaced super element
<div class="row">
    <input name="name[0][yo]"/>
    // Other elements
</div>
<div class="row">
    <input name="name[1][yo]"/>
    // other elements
</div>
</div>
```

Then in JQuery:

```
$.post('to_my_page', $('.form input, .form select, .form textarea').serialize(), function(data){
    // Done
}, 'json');
```

That should allow you to post an array of input rows to another page.

This is of course an extremely simple and basic example.

Comment: I kind of got an idea with this, will try to use this naming convention and generate the JSON

Comment: @monotheist Let me know if you need clarification :)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to accomplish that is put an id on the values, for example is you are using just a text wrap it in a span then when you need to make the JSON iterate over rows and get the data from it, i.e.:

```
var elements = []
$('#formId tr').each(function (i, e){
    elements.push({
        ElementTd1: $('#td1').val()    
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract all the data from the form you can simply use [jQuery's serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) method just like this:

```
$('form').serializeArray();
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/wrNhm/)